# Multiline RegEx read between two strings

Tags: java, regex, multiline

I know this question has been asked many times and I assure you that I have read almost all posts about RegEx on the forum and tried for hours to get a solution. But finally this thing is killing me, slowly but surely! :D
Any help is appreciated.

When I try to connect to a database and there is no db engine running, I get a `connection refused` Exception as expected. But for unknown reasons this exception is nested multiple (I don't know how many... 20, 30, 40...!!!) times and a call for `myException.getCause()` returns everytime NULL.

For that reason and because I don't want to show the whole stacktrace to users I thougt it would be nice and easy to catch just the main message with regular expressions. Unfortunately it is not as easy as I expected it to be.

First of all, do you think it is a good solution to strip down the message by cutting off the unwanted parts of a stacktrace? And if not, what do you suggest?

My Exception looks like that:

```
Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) 
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) 
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) 
        at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434) 
        at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:244) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:271) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

............. and so on ............
```

I tried many different patterns to get the String between `EXCEPTION **` and `STACKTRACE` for example:

```
EXCEPTION(\r?\n?.*?\r?\n?)*STACKTRACE
```

or

```
EXCEPTION\s*\W*(.*|\r*|\n*)+STACKTRACE
```

but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good practice for regex but I dont think it is good idea. What user can understand 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1', if you want meaningful messages you can use multi catch blocks and show user some generic information. i.e. couldnt parse data etc...

Comment: @Core-Update How about `myException.getMessage()` and `myException.getLocalizedMessage()`? both returns NULL?

Comment: @Pons I get this message (the whole stacktrace) when I use `myException.getMessage()`. The localizedMessage prints the same thing as the normal getMessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `(?s)EXCEPTION \*\*\s*(.*?)\s*STACKTRACE`.

In Java, that would be `"(?s)EXCEPTION \\*\\*\\s*(.*?)\\s*STACKTRACE"`.

Or maybe without the two `\s*`, for better performance, and `trim()` the result.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zqeP0I/1) for demo.

Comment: ok, that works! I tried the exact same pattern without `(?s)` and it didn't work... what stands this (?s) for?

Comment: @Core-Update See javadoc [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), or [Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) at `regular-expressions.info`.